# Anyone send commands to the SATO CL4NX label printer using C#?

Tags: c#, printing

I have the task of developing a C# Form Application that sends SBPL commands to the SATO CL4NX label printer and I feel like I'm beating my head against the wall (yes it hurts)! Mostly, I'm having fits trying to send an <ESC> character to the printer!

Has anyone done the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Steve

I guess you need to print label from SATO CL4NX. 
My colleagues have done it before and here is something I understand from them.

You may want to use SATO free .NET API for establishing connection or sending data to printer. This API will detect installed printer driver, detect interface (LAN/USB/RS232C/LPT), connect to the interface directly or via driver for sending data.
http://www.satoworldwide.com/software/sato-printer-interface-api.aspx

For printing label, you will need to use SBPL (SATO Barcode Programming Language). You can find some details in CL4NX programming manual.
https://www.satoamerica.com/Uploads/Files/Datasheets/CL4NX%20Programming%20Reference.pdf

I am not a C# developer thus, I cannot share actual coding samples. But hope above helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use C# to do this in web applications (see [This GitHub Repository](https://github.com/trehoffman/SATO_Label_Generator_Service)).  Most of the SATO printers I work with use the non-standard nomenclature but it's essentially the same.

Have you been able to send other data to the printer besides what you are having trouble with?

For something to try, I would recommend copying the data to the CL4NX as a file rather than sending a string of information directly to it if your commands are coming out as text on the label.